# Contractible Space: Example

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have to prove that $(\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,0)) \; \cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{S}^{1}: x\geq0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2 $ is contractible.

What I thought is that the first element of the union is contractible (because there exists one proposition that states that if we have two spaces, $X$, $Y$ for example, and one of them is contractible, then for any $Y$, $X\times Y$ has the same homotopy type of $Y$, so what I said is true, because both are contractible).

My problem is to prove that the second part of the union is contractible.

My idea is, perhaps I would have started by carrying the points of the positive semi-circle to the interval $(0,1)$ and the negative semi-circle to de points of the form $(0,y)$ with $y\in[0,1]$. Then what I have, is the first element of the union and then I have finished; nevertheless, really, I don't know if I'm doing well, because I would have proving two homopies of which I'm not sure, and really, I don't know of to proceed (I have an intuition, project the points that I said where I said).

Sorry, if I'm lying in something of my statements.

Comment: The second set is just a curved line segment; you can contract it to the endpoint $\langle 0,-1\rangle$ in the first part. Then contract the first part to a point.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. Can you give me one hint to continue? I know that I have to find an homotopy between, let be B for example (the second part of the union) and (0,-1). I don't see any homotopy (I haven't seen too many explicit homotopies) that can works... Linear homotopy? Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: I take it that your space is meant to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Have you tried drawing it? Note that $S^n\cong D^n\cup D^n$ is a union of two contractible subspaces, but is not contractible.

Comment: @pache1996: Just contract it linearly around the semicircle, much as you might contract the segment $[0,1]$ to one of its endpoints.

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I haven't seen that, sorry... So, what I have to do is to compose two homotopies, one that carries the semicircle to the point (0,-1), and then, the first space of the union in one point?

Comment: @pache1996: Carry out the first homotopy as $t$ runs from $0$ to $\frac12$ and then the second as $t$ runs from $\frac12$ to $1$.

Comment: @pache1996 also what does $x\in S^1$ with $x>0$ mean? Do you mean $(x,y)\in S^1$ with $x\geq 0$? I would contract the arc $(x,y)\in S^1$, $x,y\geq0$ to the point $(1,0)$. Then there is a straight line joining any point in $\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,0)\cup\{(1,0)\}$ with $(1,0)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  So, for example, let be $H:B\times[0,1]\rightarrow B$, $H((x,t),s)=(x,t)(1-s)+s(-1,0)$. This is the first homotopy that I have. And then, the second, $K((x,t),s)=(1-s)(x,t)$, and then, compose both... That's all? Thank to both for your help... And sorry for my several questions.

Comment: @Tyrone I only take the points of $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ that have positive $x$.

Comment: @pache1996: Your homotopies have to stay within the space, so you can’t contract the semicircle in a straight line. Polar coordinates help: at time $t\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$ send $\langle 1,\theta$ to $-\frac{\pi}2+\left(\frac12-t\right)\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}2\right)$. This contracts the semicircle around itself down into the point $\langle 0,-1\rangle$. Then for $t\in\left[\frac12,1\right]$ use any contraction of the open lower half plane to a point.

Comment: Thank to both that have answered; really, you've helped me a lot !